# Mips- How to run multiple files in Mars

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to write a program that has the user input an option and it branches and runs a program from another file.
I've tried searching for the answer, but I'm not having any luck.
I have all the files I want to use in the same directory and I changed them all to be .global and I went into the setting to assemble all files in the directory.

```
.data
options: .asciiz "Enter 1 for Roadway\nEnter 2 for Equipment\nEnter 3 for Labor\nEnter 4 for Total Projects Costs\n"

.text
.global main

main:
    li $v0, 4   
    la $a0, options
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    move $t0, $a0
    syscall

    beq $t0, 1, option1
    #beq $t0, 2, option2
    #beq $t0, 3, option3
    #beq $t0, 4, option4

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

option1:
    #this is where I'd like to run code from another file

    jr, $ra
```

Comment: Do you want to call functions in another file (so all the files are part of one large program)?  Or do you want to build two separate executable and have the first executable optionally `exec` the 2nd one, either replacing itself or waiting for the 2nd program to exit before continuing?  (The difference would be more obvious if you weren't using an all-in-one development + simulator environment; it's the difference between linking multiple source / object files into one executable vs. building separate executable binaries.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the first would work better because if they call option 4 I want the program to call all the programs.

Comment: Ok, then the word you're looking for is not "program".  It's "function", "procedure", or "subroutine".  You're making *one* program which has different functions you can call with `jal` and return from with `jr`.  I don't know the details of how MARS lets you use multiple files; in a "normal" system you'd assemble multiple asm sources into separate `.o` files, and use the linker (`ld`) to link them into one executable file (like a Windows `.exe`, if that helps).  The other option is to use a `.include` directive to include other files into one source, so it builds as if it was all 4 files.

Comment: Did you use `.global my_function` to export the `my_function` label so it's visible to the linker?  See Ped7g's answer.  If that's not it, [edit] your question with a [mcve] that reproduces the error you're getting.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, nevermind. I figured it out. I had the files in the wrong folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MARS simulator has "Settings/Assemble all files in directory" setting, which allows for multiple files to link into single program.

Example... i created new directory on disk and saved two .asm files into it:

## func.asm

```
.text

.globl printAsciiz

    # $t5 = address of ASCIIz string, modifies $v0
printAsciiz:
    # store original $a0 to stack (to preserve it)
    addi    $sp, $sp, -4
    sw      $a0, ($sp)
    # output the message from t5
    li      $v0, 4
    move    $a0, $t5
    syscall
    # restore $a0 from stack
    lw      $a0, ($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    # return from function
    jr      $ra
```

## main.asm

```
.data
    msg:    .asciiz     "Hello world\n" 

.text

.globl main
main:
    # call output function from other file
    la      $t5, msg
    jal     printAsciiz
    # terminate program
    li      $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Now when switch to the editor tab with `main.asm` (! important, when the edit tab is switched to `func.asm`, the build process will execute `func.asm` result as stand-alone app - a bit clunky and weird behaviour), and hit build button (with the "all files" setting ON), the resulting binary will start in `main.asm` by loading `$t5` with address, and then calling the `printAsciiz` function from `func.asm`.

Comment: When I run it, I get the error that it's not found in symbol table? What could be causing this?

Comment: @HarmonyKunzler What is not found in symbol table? Are both files in the "project" directory? Is the editor on the main.asm? Is the setting "Assemble all files in directory" checked ON?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I figured it out. I had the files in the wrong folder. Thank you.

Comment: So I connect the files with `jal homework5` which works and takes me there, but that code starts by using jal so when I use `jr $ra` to go back to the main file it just restarts homework5. Is there a different register I can use to specify where to jump to?

Comment: @HarmonyKunzler if you use nested `jal`, the `homework5` must first store the `$ra` somewhere, before doing its own `jal`. Usually stack is used for this. http://user.it.uu.se/~justin/Teaching/NewDarkSlides/lecture5.pdf "slide 14" shows basic example, but you may want to go through the rest of it to see if there's some good info for you. You can also save the `$ra` in some `$sX` register (and then `jr $sX` to return), but depending on the calling convention you want to follow, you should preserve those too, so unless you want to follow "everything is custom" calling convention, use stack.